# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzf

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

When I run my application in the android studio, I get the following error.

> Program type already exists: com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzf
>
> **firebase-core warning ->** All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact
>   same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime
>   crashes). Found versions 12.0.1, 10.0.1. Examples include
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1 and
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fay.flow"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.28.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.r0adkll:slidableactivity:2.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49529205/7724032

Comment: Noop, it still the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution for me

```
implementation ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.28.0',{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
```

Comment: it's worked for me, mine was: compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+' 
I changed to 
 implementation ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+',{
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    })
it's work like a charm now. Great !!!

Answer (score 7):

Had the same error. How to fix it:

In your dependencies you're using:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
```

And the warning says:

> firebase-core warning -> All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 12.0.1, 10.0.1. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1 and **com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1** less...

try to add this dependency with your version - 12.0.1 (not 10.0.1):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when I was adding two different packages to my android build (using react native).

The problem was they were using two different versions of google play services. I was able to resolve it using option 1:

**Option 1: Use Project-Wide Gradle Config:**

You can define project-wide properties (recommended) in your root /android/build.gradle, and let the library auto-detect the presence of the following properties:

```
buildscript {...}
allprojects {...}

/**
Project-wide Gradle configuration properties (replace versions as appropriate)
*/

ext {
  compileSdkVersion   = 25
  targetSdkVersion    = 25
  buildToolsVersion   = "25.0.2"
  supportLibVersion   = "25.0.2"
  googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.6.2"
  androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
}
```

**Option 2: Use Specific Gradle Config:**

If you do not have project-wide properties defined or want to use a different Google Play-Services version, use the following instead (switch 11.6.2 for the desired version):

```
  ...
  dependencies {
  ...
  implementation(project(':react-native-google-places')){
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-places'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
  }
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.2'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
  }
```

In my project I simply added:

```
ext {
  googlePlayServicesVersion = "12.0.1"
}
```

to my android/build.gradle file as per option 1.

Answer (score 2):

### what is ZZF, ZZg,ZZH, ZZA etc. whatever you get error of like this solve it by changing dependency level . some times it due to dependency missing .

its normally occurring due to your dependency mismatch i face many times and solved by changing dependency level you can see below two cases in first i got error of zzf,but second time changing first line ads dependency so now its working fine

first case:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'


implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.2@aar'
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:0.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.8.0'
implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
```

second case:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.2@aar'
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:0.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.8.0'
implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
```

in first case i get the error ,but when i change ads dependency in the first line you can see to level 10 its correct you will face this error in many key words with zzf, zzg,but its every time due to dependency mismatching at high level so change them hopefully you will enjoy it.

Answer (score 2):

I Solve this issue , Hope this will help you.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
```