# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbs

Tags: android, admob

I get this error while generating signed the application output.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.8.3, 3.99.99]'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'






dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

error message :

```
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbs
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbs, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I am using:

> Android Studio 3.1 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK
>   64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Windows 10 10.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718415/program-type-already-present-com-google-android-gms-common-api-zzf

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1230

Comment: its not working thanks

Comment: Remove this and try: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

Comment: @amanarora when i removed getting errors

Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
```

Try use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
```

**Why**

The library OneSignal use the version `12.0.1` on your android gms dependencies, and you use version `15.0.0`, the versions are incompatibles and may be the cause of problem. See code [here](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/master/OneSignalSDK/onesignal/build.gradle)

Comment: i try its and worked. but i have a problem. InterstitialAds not closing :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.8.3, 3.99.99]'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
```

Why the library `OneSignal` already have the dependency `com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbs`, seing the [github lib](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/commit/d16f1c7d40a781d6f5c1a249b791c7c9fc837c1f) we can see that it was added on last one commit. Try remove `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'`