# Program type already present: com.squareup.okhttp.Address

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, okhttp

I am trying to configure my android app to use Firebase Cloud Firestore. I also have dependencies on OKHttp3. Gradle will sync fine but I am unable to compile the app and run it. And I get the following error:

> Program type already present: com.squareup.okhttp.Address

I have followed all the steps described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart and I can run the app fine until I add this line to my build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
```

I checked the dependencies in the project and it looks like Firestore has dependencies on com.squareup.okhttp while I already have dependencies on com.squareup.okhttp3

So I don't understand why they would clash since they have different package structures.

**EDIT**

Here are my dependencies in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${rootProject.ext.kotlin_version}"
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:0.19.3'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.0'
kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.0'
compileOnly 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.3'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.3'
implementation "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.support_library_version}"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:${rootProject.ext.support_library_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:${rootProject.ext.support_library_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-ui:${rootProject.ext.support_library_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:support-fragment:${rootProject.ext.support_library_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${rootProject.ext.support_library_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${rootProject.ext.support_library_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:${rootProject.ext.support_library_version}"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${rootProject.ext.play_services_version}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${rootProject.ext.play_services_version}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${rootProject.ext.play_services_version}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${rootProject.ext.play_services_version}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:${rootProject.ext.play_services_version}"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${rootProject.ext.firebase_version}"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:${rootProject.ext.firebase_version}"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${rootProject.ext.firebase_version}"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:${rootProject.ext.firebase_version}"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:${rootProject.ext.firebase_version}"

// Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also

// explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.9'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.13.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.4.2'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.tonicartos:superslim:0.4.13'
implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'konifar:fab-transformation:1.0.0'
implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.3.3'
implementation 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
implementation 'ru.gildor.coroutines:kotlin-coroutines-retrofit:0.9.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.1'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.7.1'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.1'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.7.1'
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.6.1'
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.6.1'
testImplementation 'org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9'
testImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
testImplementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
androidTestImplementation fileTree(include: 'robotium-solo-5.3.0.jar', dir: 'libs')

//Screenshots
androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.2.0'

// Cucumber
androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.5'
androidTestImplementation('info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.4') {
    exclude module: 'cucumber-jvm-deps'
}
androidTestImplementation('info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.4') {
    exclude module: 'cucumber-jvm-deps'
}
androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.3'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'

// Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'

// Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'

}
```

Comment: Please add the content of your build.grade file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351721/android-studio-errorprogram-type-already-present

Comment: tried the different answers proposed in the link you sent, but no difference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## FIXED

<s>It turned out the problem was not related to OkHttp - it was related to the Dexer compiler in the new version of android studio (3.0.0 and above) 
Going into the gradle.properties file and adding this line:</s>

```
android.enableD8=false
```

solved my problem. The app now compiles normally

## EDIT

The comments are right - you should *NOT* do this. The problem turned out to be that the project had gradle dependencies conflicting with .jar files manually imported. If you do have this problem, check if you've not got:

1. Different versions of the same library imported by different modules in Gradle
2. Jar file of a library you're also importing with Gradle

Comment: This works even though Compiler is giving deprecation warning about that.

Comment: Where in your file did you put this line?

Comment: Can you please tell me where to add in the gradle.properties?

Comment: android studio says :
Warning:The option 'android.enableD8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Going into the `gradle.properties` file and adding this line:

```
android.enableR8=false
android.enableD8=false
```

I hope this works.