# Program type already present: retrofit2.Converter$Factory Retrofit compilation error

Tags: java, android, gradle, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit library and it gives the compile error

> Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   retrofit2.Converter$Factory, sources=[Unknown source file], tool
>   name=Optional.of(D8)}

My `app/build.gradle` file is like

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2') {exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' }
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.github.shrikanth7698:Custom-Navigation-Drawer:v0.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/retrofit-2.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/converter-gson-2.4.0.jar')
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev369-1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
}
```

Comment: check if this works https://stackoverflow.com/a/50003848/8009433

Comment: it shows like "Multiple dex files define Lretrofit2/converter/gson/package-info;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used both volley and retrofit. That's what made the error. I started the project in a project without using volley and it was solved

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from your gradle file (you have already added them at the bottom):

```
implementation files('libs/retrofit-2.4.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/converter-gson-2.4.0.jar')
```