# Program type already present: com.google.gdata.client.Query$CategoryFilter

Tags: android, google-contacts-api, mobile-development

I have been implementing GOOGLE CONTACT API v3 (below is the link)(https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/)

I have followed the documentation and added all supported required Libraries into my app and all dependencies error have gone from my code

But when I tried run/building, it shows me this error

> Program type already present: com.google.gdata.client.Query$CategoryFilter
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.gdata.client.Query$CategoryFilter, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

I tried googleing but didnt found exact error solution but I have noticed that most fix for this kind of issue is to up/downgrade build version

So, i was building on api 28 so I downgraded to 27.1.1 but same error

this is how my build.gradle looks

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.murtaza.contactsync"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/gdata-core-1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gdata-client-1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gdata-contacts-3.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/guava-11.0.2.jar')
}
```

and this are all the import

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.gdata.client.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.contacts.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.contacts.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
```

please guide me where and what Im doing wrong or How to fix this issue so that I can implement google contact api v3

I have used exact documented code for this

please help me here

Comment: Try to update your SDK build system. Also, one suggestion from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351721/android-studio-errorprogram-type-already-present) is to check the compile version in you App settings with the API level you've built your project with.

Comment: Thanks, but I got to know that Contact API is depreciated and now use People Contact Api instead and its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Google Contact API is depreciated so instead wasting time I used Poeple
>   API which is replaceable to Contact API and its working like a charm

Google People API links:
https://developers.google.com/people

Tutorial for People API link:
https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/people-api-android-tutorial-1/

Sample Code Github link:
https://github.com/simformsolutions/Google-People-API-Sample