# Android Studio Error: Program type already present: org.objectweb.asm.Edge

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I can't build my project because of this: "Program type already present: org.objectweb.asm.Edge"
There also was error before: "Program type already present:org.objectweb.asm.ByteVector"
Here's gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.7.2'
    implementation group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: '2.0.0'

    //  Rx dependencies
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7'

    // Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
    // explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    //OkHttp
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.5.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

### Update

Looks like the problem is in JsonPath. I tried to exclude dependencies but nothing changed:

```
implementation (group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: '2.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.ow2.asm', module: 'asm'
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
        exclude group: 'org.objectweb.asm'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know for sure what's going on without a stack trace, but I'm inclined to think that one of your dependencies has some duplicate import...

Have you had a look at this thread? 
[Android Studio - Error:Program type already present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351721/android-studio-errorprogram-type-already-present)