# Error: Program type already present: com.appsflyer.AFExecutor

Tags: appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

I'm struggling to implement AppsFlyer on Android using Java.
I have looked into a couple of posts already such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351721/android-studio-errorprogram-type-already-present), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean).
Here is the entire error message: `[org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: com.appsflyer.AFExecutor","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}`

The version
AppsFlyer SDK: 5.+
Android Studio: 3.5.2

Situation

- I have done till [4.1](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032126#integration-41-whitelisting-your-test-device) of this guide so far so good.
- On `AndroidManifest.xml`, the main class name of AF has implemented with `android.name` attribute.
- On `AndroidManifest.xml`, `receiver` tag commented out (because in this phase I don't believe I do not need a precise data tracking feature.)

What I have tried.

- `./gradlew app:dependencies | less` To find out `AFExecutor` in other dependencies
- To exclude the program

```
implementation ('com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:5.+'){
        exclude module: 'com.appsflyer'
    }
```

```
implementation ('com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:5.+'){
        exclude module: 'AFExecutor'
    }
```

If you have any insights, I'd love to hear that.

Comment: Can you post your project gradle dependency, please

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However, I managed to solve it by myself. You could see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring a bunch of dependencies, I found the solution. The reason was there was a conflict between `com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:5.+` and `AF-Android-SDK.jar` which had installed manually. After removing the JAR file and built again, I could make it at last! Thank you so much for sharing your experiences, however, the solution was simple!

Answer (score 0):

Try `./gradlew clean`, `clean project` and `invalidate caches and restart`. If does not help than delete all `build` and `.idea` folders, `.iml` files.